# WaterMarkExtender Overriding TextBox Values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have three textboxes with watermark on all of them.
In the OnChange event of first textbox I set the value of the second textbox with JavaScript.
This works, but the text I set this way shows like a watermark - and when I click on the textbox it is empty, when I leave it it shows again the original watermark text.

How can I get the text I set by JavaScript to display as the entered text, not the watermark text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hacky, but it works. You need to use the extender's set_Text in order to get it to realize that you have set the text, not the watermark.

```
<!-- not this: -->
onchange="document.getElementById('<%= textbox.ClientID %>').value = 'foo'"

<!-- this: -->
onchange="$find('<%= watermark.ClientID %>').set_Text('foo')"
```